# Случай синтаксической омонимии

Tags: синтаксис, омоним

Прилагательное ***нужный***.

Вот его краткие формы (синтаксически - в функции именной части сказуемого при согласовании по роду и числу с подлежащим):

он нужен

она нужна

оно нужно

они нужны

Пусть в роли подлежащего будет слово ***окно***.

Получаем: ***Окно нужно***, т. е подлежащее — cуществительное среднего рода единственного числа; сказуемое — краткое прилагательное среднего рода единственного числа.

...................................................................................................................................................................................................

Однако существует и предикатив ***нужно***, управляющий винительным/родительным падежами дополнения (все примеры из словарей Кузнецова, Ожегова и Ушакова):

Срочно нужно (кого, что?) врача.

Мне нужно (кого, что?) сто рублей.

Для этого пирога нужно (кого, что?) орехи.

Мне нужно (кого, чего?) денег.

...................................................................................................................................................................................................

Хорошо, ставим в позицию такого дополнения опять слово ***окно***.

Получаем: ***Нужно (кого, что?) окно***.

Это уже предикатив с дополнением, хотя внешне он ничем не отличается  от сочетания подлежащее + краткое прилагательное.

...................................................................................................................................................................................................

И прилагательное, и предикатив — оба управляют дательным субъектным.

*Мне* нужно окно - ***предикатив***

Окно нужно *мне* - ***краткое прилагательное*** (сравните с другими родами и числами: магнитофон *нужен* мне, собака *нужна* мне, конфеты *нужны* мне).

Получаем синтаксическую омонимию, при которой ***окно нужно мне*** может пониматься двояко: либо как краткое прилагательное — сказуемое при именном подлежащем, либо как предикатив, категория состоянии с зависимым именем-дополнением.

Не так ли?

Comment: Предикатив - это условие к глаголу. Какое условие и к какому глаголу в предложении "мне нужно окно"?

Answer (score 0):

1. Предложения с одинаковым **лексическим составом** могут иметь разное толкование. Очень известный пример: ***Мать любит дочь.***
   В случае возникновения такой синтаксической омонимии на помощь приходит порядок слов в предложении и контекст.
2. ***Мне нужно окно.***

Слово ***нужно***  может быть **предикативом** в безличном предложении или **кратким прилагательным** в роли сказуемого в двусоставном предложении (для сущ. среднего рода). Нужный **смысл** при такой синтаксической омонимии определяется **порядком** слов в разных **ситуациях.**

**Вариант 1** (обычный)

— *Что вы  хотите у нас заказать?  —  **Мне нужно окно.***  Потребность лица в окне. Предикатив в безличном предложении.

**Вариант 2** (при заданной теме)

— *Кому сейчас нужно **это окно**, не будем его менять. — **Мне нужно окно!***  Необходимость окна для лица. Краткое прилагательное в двусоставном предложении, инверсия.  Или (без инверсии): ***Окно** нужно мне.*

**Большой толковый словарь русского языка**

НУЖНО, в функц. **сказ.** 1. **обычно с инф.** Необходимо, следует; надо (1.Н). Н. написать письма. Мне н. поговорить с тобой. Мы не знаем, как н. хозяйствовать. 2. **кого-что или чего. Требуется, следует иметь**. Срочно н. врача. Для этой работы н. двух человек. **Мне н. сто рублей.** Для этого пирога н. орехи. Очень нужно, в зн. частицы. Выражает нежелание, несогласие, протест. Будем ждать дочь? - Очень нужно!

**НУЖНЫЙ,** -ая, -ое; -жен, -жна, -жно, нужны и нужны. 1. **Такой**, без которого трудно, невозможно обойтись; **необходимый.** Н-ая книга. Н-ые вещи. Нужной суммы у меня не было. Дать н-ые указания. / с инф. Не считаю нужным вникать в этот конфликт. Председатель нашёл нужным прервать оратора. Н. человек (полезный, жизненно необходимый). 2. **Соответствующий, подходящий** для кого-, чего-л.; правильный. Взять н-ое направление. Поместить в нужном месте, нужным образом, в нужном свете (так, как нужно, как следует; как требуется). Нужен как собаке пятая нога (см. Нога). Нужность, -и; ж.